# how to draw something using a turtlesimbot and stop that bot, spawn another turtlesimbot at that coord, and draw using the 2nd bot?

Tags: ros2, beginner, turtlesim

```
import rclpy
from geometry_msgs.msg import Twist
import math

def draw_line():
    rclpy.init()
    node = rclpy.create_node('draw_line_node')

    pub = node.create_publisher(Twist, 'turtle1/cmd_vel', 10)
    timer_period = 0.1  
    timer = node.create_timer(timer_period, timer_callback)

    rclpy.spin(node)

def timer_callback():

    msg = Twist()
    linear_speed = 1.0  
    angular_speed = 0.0 
    msg.linear.x = linear_speed
    msg.linear.y = 0.0
    msg.linear.z = 0.0
    msg.angular.x = 0.0
    msg.angular.y = 0.0
    msg.angular.z = angular_speed
    pub.publish(msg)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    draw_line()
```

This code will make a line, how do i now call another turtlebot and create another line perpendicular to where it stopped??

Comment: you have to spawn a second turtlebot before you can draw with it